# BoundingRect collision detection

Tags: pyqt5, collision-detection, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

How i can detect which side of bounding rect(left,right,bottom,top) of QGraphicsPixmapItem in the QGraphicsScene was the collision with another item?
I cant find any info about this in Pyqt5 Docs

Comment: You have to find it on your own by comparing those bouding rects. That's simple geometry.

Comment: For example, assuming that those items *do* collide, if `x` of the right side of the other rectangle is greater than the left side of the current one, than it *probably* means that it collides on the left side, unless the right side of the current rect is greater than the left side of the other, which means that it collides on the other side. As said, it's basic geometry. If you have difficulties understanding the process, I'd suggest you to simply use paper and pencil to help you visualize the relation between those rectangles and their coordinates.

Comment: Items which touch on a corner pixel will collide on two sides. And if the items are fully side-by-side, at least one item will touch *two* corner pixels (and thus collide on three sides). So I think you first need to decide how you want to resolve this ambiguity. One possible approach might be to create a rect from each corner and each edge (i.e. eight in all) and then check which ones intersect with the bounding-rect of the colliding item. (It might help to imagine a king on a chessboard and consider which squares it can move to).